# Is there a way to quickly replace left half of my sculpt with mirror image of right half?

Tags: mirror, sculpt

My sculpt model has become a little unsymmetrical and I'd like to replace the left half with a mirror image of the right.  I know there's an option for this under Dyntopo, but that leaves artifacts.  My center line is still in tact - is there something that will simply delete the left half of my model and replace it with the right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try going into edit mode, then under mesh options, symmetrize. On the popup option choose direction of the symmetry (ie. -x to x)